# MySQL - What is wrong with this trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create this trigger and am getting an error for the UPDATE line.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS upd_signedup;

CREATE TRIGGER upd_signedup
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE tbl_user_stats SET signups = signups + 1;
END
```

EDIT: I have set the delimiter to $$ but can't create this trigger:

```
 drop trigger if exists upd_signedup$$

 CREATE TRIGGER upd_signedup
 BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_users
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  UPDATE tbl_user_stats SET signups = signups + 1$$
 END
```

Comment: What MySQL client are you executing this with? Did you change the statement delimiter as appropriate for your client?

Comment: phpMyAdmin. I have not changed the delimiter.

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Comment: I believe PHPMyAdmin has a field to set the delimiter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080681/store-procedures-in-phpmyadmin for an example of what your statements should look like (where `$$` is the chosen delimiter in those examples)

Comment: Ok, I set the delimiter to $$ and was able to create the trigger, after I removed the UPDATE statement.  I am still receiving an error if I include the update statement. (check the manual ... for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5).

Comment: The update should end with `;`. Add another `$$` after `END`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you misunderstood the concept of using DELIMITER while defining triggers.

`;`(semi colon) is a regular delimiter, an indicator for the end of an executable statement.
But when you are defining a trigger or a stored procedure you define body with multiple executable statements like variable declarations and SQL statements.

The use of `;` indicates the SQL engine that the statement reached an end and it is time to compile and execute it. But unless the body of trigger or stored procedure *END*s, there is no meaning in executing internal statements of trigger/sp body. To stop processing such statements we use a custom `DELIMITER` like `//` or `$$` or something that you are comfortable with and frequently do not use in the body part of trigger/sp definition. MySQL then understands that a statement ends only when it finds your custom defined DELIMITER say `$$` or `//`.

An example is shown below:

```
mysql>
mysql> set @cnt=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> -- drop trigger if exists trig_bef_del_on_tbl;
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create trigger trig_bef_del_on_tbl before delete on tbl
    ->   for each row begin
    ->     set @cnt = if(@cnt is null, 1, (@cnt+1));
    ->
    ->     /* for cross checking save loop count */
    ->     insert into rows_affected values ( @cnt );
    ->   end;
    -> //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> delimiter ;
mysql>
mysql> -- now let us test the delete operation
mysql> delete from tbl where i like '%1%';
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

**Refer to**:

- My answer to a query on [mysql delete triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11236902/767881)
- [Create Trigger Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html)

Answer (score 0):

Trigger's body has only one command, so you can use this simple syntax, without BEGIN-END clause and without DELIMITERs:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_signedup
  BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_users
  FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE tbl_user_stats SET signups = signups + 1;
```

Comment: If I want to eventually add a SELECT statement before the UPDATE statement would I need the BEGIN-END clause?

Comment: Yes, you will need to add that clause. Note, it is possible that SELECT and UPDATE statements can be united in one common UPDATE statement.